# Whitelisting Dialogflow API URL through firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, dialogflow-es, firewall

I'm trying to make calls to Dialogflow API from a corporate network, so I need to request some outbound rules to be added to the firewall.

The URLs I'm trying to hit in my API calls are in the form:  https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/*

I've tried whitelisting dialogflow.googleapis.com, and I have also tried whitelisting googleapis.l.google.com, which is the CNAME record for dialogflow.googleapis.com to no avail.

The connection still times out when trying to ping/curl from behind the firewall. What domain/IP range do I need to whitelist to allow for outbound calls to Dialogflow?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is straight from the horse's mouth (Google DNS). One of them should work.

```
$ nslookup
> server 8.8.8.8
Default server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
> dialogflow.googleapis.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
dialogflow.googleapis.com   canonical name = googleapis.l.google.com.
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.7.138
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.7.170
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.9.202
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.12.234
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.7.234
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.8.10
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.13.74
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.13.234
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.15.106
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.15.74
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.164.138
Name:   googleapis.l.google.com
Address: 172.217.164.170
>
```